# when to load data from api to local db in flutter application?

Tags: android, flutter, api, asynchronous, sqflite

I am working on a flutter application , application load some dynamic data from an api x , I have maintained a local data copy of data provided from api x , The Source of api x  keeps changing as admin enters new data from its end ( a panel  have created for admin to insert data in db ) .
Now my question is since the data from api x keeps changing and there is not time limit for it to get changed  it may change five minutes from now , i may change 1 hr from now or it may change 1 day later . When Should i copy data from that api x to my localdatabase sqflite that i am maintaining in flutter .
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options. 1st - You can fix some time interval. i.e. after every 1 hour your will be sync. 2nd - You can implement notification or socket event. i.e. every time admin update any data, app will get one notification/ socket event, so base on that you can call API and sync your local database.